# How can I invite my partner to my github repository?

Tags: github

I've created a [private repo](https://github.com/montao/oslab) but my partner says he cannot access it. How do I go about inviting a partner to code with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your repo `settings` there's a collaborator's tab. You can then add your partner to collaborate on your project from there.